# Pug - Include a Markdown File with Embedded HTML

Tags: javascript, markdown, pug, jstransform

**To the point**

Is there a way I can get Pug to include embedded HTML in a Markdown file as part of the actual HTML and not simply plain text?

**Details**

I have a Pug template that uses the `jstransformer-markdown-it` filter. The input Markdown file has embedded HTML. That Markdown file looks like this (`video.md`)

```
# Watch this video!

This video demonstrates *the power of something something*.

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

More Markdown here.
----------------
```

The template to load this Markdown file looks like this (`entry.pug`)

```
html
  include head.pug

  body
    header Article

    div(id="main")
      article
        include:markdown-it video.md
```

This is then served up via Express like so (`index.js`).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('entry');
}

app.listen(3000);
```

When loading this content in the browser, most of the Markdown from the file is converted to HTML successfully. However the embedded markup (the `iframe` in this case) is inserted as plain text.

Is there a way I can get Pug to include embedded HTML in a Markdown file as part of the actual HTML and not as just text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way, but it's undocumented!
https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2200

Change `include:markdown-it(html)`

You can also install markdown-it plugins, and include them with e.g. `include:markdown-it(plugins=['markdown-it-decorate'])`

I haven't found a way to turn on plugins by default, so you need to put them in every pug include.

Comment: How do you install this plugin?